# QGIS -- Extract Values from KDE raster to orginal point data layer

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, extract

After performing a heatmap on QGIS of my cheetah location dataset, I would like to extract values from my kernel density estimate (KDE) raster data layer to my orignal point data layer used to create it in order to extract 50% of my values from my KDE.

I went on the POINT SAMPLING TOOL in the puglin toolbars. I only have one choice for the Layer containing sampling points --> Cheetah_Coalition (discrete points layer), and if I click on the "Clipped (mask): Band 1 (raster)" within the Layers with fields, the answer is that "An error has occurred while exucuting Python code; Null geometry cannot be converted to a point."[image]

Can anyone help me to extracting my raster value to my original point data layer?

Comment: I can see this is Karongwe Private Game Reserve so I am assume this is GVI collected data? Is this from Jabu and Djuma?

Answer (score 0):

I do this regularly using the "Sample raster values" tool, which will do what I think you want.

It should create a new vector layer of your Cheetah_Coalition dataset, but with an extra column in the attributes table with values sampled from the KDE ratser.  If there are specific points in the Cheetah_Coalition dataset for which you want to sample the KDE, then you can select these before running the tool and check the box for "selected features only".

I have had the tool return the error "Null geometry cannot be converted to a point", but got round it by selecting a new layer of points in the "input point layer" drop down and then going back to select the layer I actually wanted to use.